# Active Model Serializer customize json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, activemodel, active-model-serializers

So I'm having a problem with ams. I'm using Rails 5.2 and I read lots of tutorials and even when I did exactly what they showed I still have something that they don't and I didn't find answer on google.

I have model Course, Video, Quiz and Segment. 
Course has many segment, segment can be video or quiz (I'm using sti).
This is how I wrote it:

## app/models/course.rb

```html
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title ,presence: true
  validates :author ,presence: true

  has_many :videos
  has_many :quizs
  has_many :segments


end
```

## app/models/segment.rb

```html
class Segment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course

end
```

## app/models/quiz.rb

```html
class Quiz < Segment
  validates :course_id ,presence: true
  validates :name ,presence: true

  belongs_to :course
end
```

## app/models/video.rb

```html
class Video < Segment
  validates :course_id ,presence: true
  validates :name ,presence: true

  belongs_to :course
end
```

## app/controllers/courses_controller.rb

```html
class CoursesController < InheritedResources::Base
  def show
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    render json: @course.attributes
  end

  def index
    @courses = Course.all
    render json: @courses
  end

end
```

## app/serializers/course_serializer.rb

```html
class CourseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :title, :author
  has_many :segments

end
```

[and this is what is showed me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRDYQ.png)

I have couple of problems:

1. I don't know where this data name come from and I don't know how to change it or hide it.
2. even when I request to see one course I get the created date and other stuff I didn't want, although I configured it so I only see title and author.
3. I want to know if I can custom the json response so I won't see the title of the relations or change it's name.

Answer (score 0):

1. You haven't created a `SegmentSerializer`. By default, AMS will serialize all fields.

`class SegmentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :name
    end`

2. Remove the `attributes` method call. It returns a `Hash` and then your serializer is not used.

```

```
 class CoursesController < InheritedResources::Base
  def show
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    render json: @course
  end

  def index
    @courses = Course.all
    render json: @courses
  end

end
```

```

3. Use the `key` option

   `has_many :segments, key: :your_key`

Comment: I did what you wrote me and it hasn't changed

Comment: Edited my answer.